# nanoc or ruby link_to questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nanoc

I have an href tag    `<li><a href="/"><span></span>Home</a></li>` Which i need to convert to `<li> <%= link_to('Home', '/Home/') %></li>` But when I enter `<span></span>` it reads an error. How do i enter `<span></span>` . So that its the same as href tag above ? `<span></span>` needs to be there as it is a css fix ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `<span></span>` in your first argument, so `link_to '<span></span>Home', '/'` should give you exactly what you want.